# Unsupported operand type for - list and list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using an older version of python which doesnt have support to subtract dict's.

```
d1={'ab': ['3'], 'hij': ['1200']}
d2={'ab': ['1'], 'hij': ['600']}
```

Basically my code looks like this:

```
  for key in d1.keys():
        if key in d2:
            d3[key]=d1[key]-d2[key]
```

output should be like

```
d2={'ab': ['2'], 'hij': ['600']}
```

It returns unsupported operand type for - : list and list.
Any ideas on how to get around this

Comment: Please post the contents of d1 and d2.

Comment: You're trying to subtract one list from another.  What do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: Another list containing the difference of the values of the keys

Comment: Why are the strings even stored in lists? You could have a simple

` 'ab': 1244.568`

You should also convert the strings to ints if you want to subtract them

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's going wrong. The way you expect it to work isn't the way it actually works. You will need to do research into how to access the contents of a list (and then you will need to do research into how to convert strings into integers). Please at least attempt to resolve issues yourself, and do independent research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the first values from the list and cast them to `int`s.

```
d1 = {'ab': ['3'], 'hij': ['1200']}
d2 = {'ab': ['1'], 'hij': ['600']}
d3 = {}

for key in d1.keys():
    if key in d2:
        d3[key] = int(d1[key][0]) - int(d2[key][0])

print d3
```

Output:

```
{'hij': 600, 'ab': 2}
```

---

To support floats, you need to cast to `float`. If you want to have 4 digits of precision, then you can use the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function.

```
d1 = {'ab': ['3.2462353'], 'hij': ['1200.223353']}
d2 = {'ab': ['1.346733'], 'hij': ['600.252341']}
d3 = {}

for key in d1.keys():
    if key in d2:
        num1 = float(d1[key][0])
        d3[key] = round(float(d1[key][0]) - float(d2[key][0]), 4)

print d3
```

Output:

```
{'hij': 599.971, 'ab': 1.8995}
```

Comment: Had to use float since I had some non integers too. Anyway to return just the magnitude and just 4 significant digits rather than soo many I am currently getting. Also, I don't think it worked since I get the same difference values for all keys

Comment: Updated to support floats with 4 digits of precision. And yeah, it works. Check the input output I did. It's correct.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by same difference.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. Just one last question, Say I had more values inside the each key, so, If I wanted to compare the second value of d1 with the second value of d2, just changing the [0] to [1] is sufficient right. Also, If I wanted the difference of all the values in each key in d1 and d2, then how would I store it in d3

Comment: Yes, changing it to `[1]` will get the second element. Not sure what you mean by *difference of all the values*.

Comment: I want d3 to be something like {'ab': ['1.8995', '2.333'], 'hij': ['599.971', '455.2312'], basically have the difference for both [0] and [1] in the same dict

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
d1={'ab': ['3'], 'hij': ['1200']}
d2={'ab': ['1'], 'hij': ['600']} 
d3={}
for key in d1.keys():
    if key in d2:
        d3[key] = [str(int(d1[key][i]) - int(d2[key][i])) for i in xrange(len(d1[key]))]
print d3
```

Comment: It says invalid syntax

Comment: Corrected. Try it now.

Comment: Unsupported operand type for -: str and str

Comment: It won't work because the "numbers" in the lists are actually strings...

Answer (score 0):

You can't subtract lists like so.

You could instead use a *dictionary comprehensio*n and then `zip` the lists so you can then subtract their content:

```
d1={'ab': ['3'], 'hij': ['1200']}
d2={'ab': ['1'], 'hij': ['600']}

d3 = {k: ['{}'.format(int(i) - int(j)) for i, j in zip(d1[k], d2[k])] for k in d1}
print(d3)
# {'hij': ['600'], 'ab': ['2']}
```

Notice the items where casted to `int` and then back to string using string formatting. Might be better if your data was actually stored as integers in the first place.

Comment: Says invalid syntax for me

Comment: I want to believe you didn't copy the `>>>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at d1[key] and d2[key] to get an idea of what the error is about ? Well if not you should have, that's the first step of debugging code: looking where it failed and what was involved in the failure.

So the explaination of your problem is the following d1['ab'] is not a number, it is a list , that list  is `['3']` to be more precise.  So writing `d1['ab'] - d2['ab']`  translates to `['3'] - ['1']` and that would be equivalent to doing `list() - list()` and as the error states there is no way to substract two list, the operation is simply not defined. So what  you want is to take what is **inside** the list and not the list itself but be carefull inside those lists you only have **strings** not actual numbers so you have to convert the string to a number and only then you will be able to do the expected substaction.

But all that is fairly tedious and I assume the mistake is that you didn't totaly undersand the syntax of dictionnaries when you wrote the code. You don't have to put the numbers as strings and inside a list to put them in the dict, you could directly put the number as is : `d1={'ab': 3, 'hij': 1200}`  is perfectly valid python code. Then when you call `d1['ab']` you directly get the number you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I used "d1.setdefault(name,[]).append(number)" to get the dictionary. changing it to append(float(number)) should do the trick right